# AngularJS mysql filter multiple element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Hi this is my hotel project. But I'm having a problem with a filter. 
I want to filter the data in the amenities column.

This is: [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/zcgs7yf6/15/)

It works if you select a single checkbox but it does not work if you select multiple checkboxes.

I suspect the problem arises from indexof instead of what I can use. What method should I follow?

How to change this line: `indexOf(x);`

This is my bad code:

```
//PROBLEM FILTER HERE 

$scope.am_en = function()
{
    //get input value
    x = $(".hosting_amenities input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
    //filter
    $scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
        return location.amenities.indexOf(x) !== -1;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed caused by the function `$scope.am_en`, in the declaration of the inner function `$scope.ot_Filter`

When you select multiple checkboxes, your `x` variable is an array of objects, so you should do a loop and can create a variable to check whether the element should be shown or not. You can do it as follows:

```
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
    var shouldBeShown = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (location.amenities.indexOf(x[i]) !== -1) {
                shouldBeShown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return shouldBeShown;
};
```

I modified your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcgs7yf6/17/), so that you can see this solution working properly.

Comment: This is great. I've been trying to solve it for days. thank you so much..

Comment: How can I hide all of the rooms if there is no TV in the room. Can we filter with or without filter? For example: if wifi and tv checked. If the TV does not have any room, the result is null

Comment: I recommend you to post new doubts as separated questions, so that the whole community will know that you still have something to solve.